# IntelliJ IDEA 12 and Android, debug signed apk

Tags: android, intellij-idea

How do I tell IntelliJ IDEA 12 to sign as debug the apk it installs on the device when I click on Run/Debug?

I can do it manually with an artifact, but that's beyond the point.

Answer (score 2):

I found a way around this.

First I create the artifact, then I set up a new run configuration in which I remove the Make step, add the Build artifacts step and select which artifact I want built. Then I create two new External tool commands and add them to the chain.

The commands are:

`adb uninstall APPLICATION_NAMESPACE`

`adb install -r PATH_TO_APK_FROM_FRAGMENT`

Works well with Deploy application and launch activity, too.

(You can leave the Make step there, but you're compiling the same source twice, and it's not a fast operation considering Android.)

---

Here is a screenshot of how to define the external tool commands in IntelliJ:

[image: IntelliJ Run Configuration]

Comment: Can you **please add a screenshot** of the run configuration you made? I have problems setting up the commands. Did you use `Run External tool`?

Comment: @jjd Sorry for seeing this so late. Yes, here is a screenshot. I have to blur out the name, but you'll figure it out. Yes, I use `Run External tool` and set the tools up as mentioned before. [Screenshot](http://oi40.tinypic.com/24mdrvr.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

The docs say

> An unsigned package can be extracted **only** through an Android artifact
>   definition with the Debug or Release unsigned package mode specified.

So unless someone else knows a custom hack I think this is the way to go